# Using the Numeric keyboard from a Gluon mobile application

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

In Android, to have the keyboard be numeric only, you only need to set the `inputType` as `number`. In Javafx, you must make sure you have the correct properties set, in this case,

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
```

and then you set `textfield.getProperties().put("vkType", "numeric");`

This is not working for me at all. I have tried to add it in `Gradle` build, which did not work.

I have tried adding it in the `init` method, as below.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
    addViewFactory(HOME_SCREEN_VIEW, () -> new HomeView().getView());
    addViewFactory(STATION_LIST_VIEW, () -> new StationListView().getView());
    addViewFactory(STATION_VIEW, () -> new StationView().getView());
    addViewFactory(CHOOSE_FLIGHT_VIEW, () -> new ChooseFlightView().getView());
    addViewFactory(SETTINGS_VIEW, () -> new SettingsView().getView());
    addViewFactory(LOGIN_VIEW, () -> new LoginView().getView());
    addViewFactory(EDIT_PREF_VIEW, () -> new EditingPrefView().getView());
    addViewFactory(SPLASH_VIEW,() -> new SplashView().getView());
    addViewFactory(OVERLOAD_VIEW, () -> new OverloadView().getView());
    addViewFactory(ADDUSER_VIEW, () -> new AddUserView().getView());
}
```

It also did not work. I have looked into the `.apk` and I found a `javafx.platform.properties.` file, which has `android.com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true` in it. If I change the properties to add in the `android.`, it still does not work.

How can I make this work? I am using a normal JavaFx `TextField`, not `Gluon TextField`.

If at all possible, I would actually prefer to use the native Android numeric keyboard, but I haven't found any way to do that either.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a Gluon Android app. My solution is not ideal but this is how I circled around it! I created a GridPane once the textfield was clicked. for example `textField.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            numericKeypad();
       });` and my numericKeypad method contains a gridpane with buttons (with numeric text on it) and styles of the gridpane and buttons. at the end of the method I used this `view.setBottom(gridPane);` which sets the bottom to keyPad when you click on the textfield! and I after they are done editing I set`view.setBottom(null);` so that it gives it the feeling of a keyboard popping from the bottom as a regular keyboard. As I said this is not ideal or what you are looking for exactly but I hope this helps!